# Is 'vacated' in open address hash table only capable to store one variable?

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm studying Master Algorithms with C and in the open address hash table program, the author defined: `void *vacated;` to point to the vacated position in a hash table. So if I would like to delete 2 values in the hash table consecutively. Is that true that is it not possible as `vacated` will point to the last deleted variable?

If I would like to delete two variables of the same hash value consecutively. I think this would be different from deleting two variables of different hash value.

In the function `ohtbl_remove`, I could not find a statement to NULL the variable to be deleted. How does it manages to delete a variable if I would like to delete variables consecutively? Thanks.

```
int ohtbl_remove(OHTbl *htbl, void **data) {

int                position,
               i;

/*****************************************************************************
*                                                                            *
*  Use double hashing to hash the key.                                       *
*                                                                            *
*****************************************************************************/


for (i = 0; i < htbl->positions; i++) {

   position = (htbl->h1(*data) + (i * htbl->h2(*data))) % htbl->positions;

   if (htbl->table[position] == NULL) {

  /***********************************************************************
  *                                                                      *
  *  Return that the data was not found.                                 *
  *                                                                      *
  ***********************************************************************/

  return -1;

  }

else if (htbl->table[position] == htbl->vacated) {

  /***********************************************************************
  *                                                                      *
  *  Search beyond vacated positions.                                    *
  *                                                                      *
  ***********************************************************************/

  continue;

  }

else if (htbl->match(htbl->table[position], *data)) {

  /***********************************************************************
  *                                                                      *
  *  Pass back the data from the table.                                  *
  *                                                                      *
  ***********************************************************************/

  *data = htbl->table[position];
  htbl->table[position] = htbl->vacated;
  htbl->size--;
  return 0;

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several elements in the list could all point at the same `vacated` member — so no, it is not true that you can only have one vacated slot in the table.  You can also have several consecutive vacated slots.  The links will point to the next entry; the data pointer will point to `vacated` so you know that once upon a time there was an element here and you should continue searching beyond it.

Comment: yes, that was the first mistake i made implementing mine [here](https://github.com/lightness1024/cpp_open_addr_hashmap_container), If one looks at how google does it, i think i recall seeing they call a garbage compaction function if they notice there is a "deleted" flag pollution above 50%.